# Generic method for ObservableCollection and IEnumerable

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

I have this function:

```
public static double MaxValue(IEnumerable<double> Collection)
{
    double max = Collection.First();
    foreach (double d in Collection)
        if (d > max)
            max = d;

    return max;
}
```

1. If I define a generic method: `MaxValue<T>(IEnumerable<T> Collection)` how can I assure that no one could use that on a custom type without `<` `>` defined? Is this a good thing to be worried of?
2. How can I code just one method that works both for `IEnumerable` and `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: Why not just use [`Max`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.max(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method from LINQ?

Comment: why you don't want tot use normal max function of ienumerable?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb535031(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @soon it can be an answer, and this way it will be more useful for future readers

Comment: @soon It's just for my personal curiosity, I'd like to know how I can define a function like this :-)

Comment: @RezaAghaei, I just didn't get the idea of the question, that is why I posted this as a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: @misiMe, So, you question is *"How to implement `Max` extension by hands"*? If so, you could search for `Max` implementation at [github.com](https://github.com/dotnet) repository - I sure, LINQ should be open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I define a generic method: `MaxValue<T>(IEnumerable<T> Collection)`
>   how can I assure that no one could use that on a custom type without < > defined? Is this a good thing to be worried of?

If I understand what you're saying, you can't use the generic method as defined here at all. If you want, you need to constraint `T` to implement `IComparable<T>`, so you can compare it against another value, or take an `IComparer<T>` in your method (and then there's no need for the constraint):

```
public T MaxValue<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    T maxValue = default(T);
    foreach (var element in collection)
    {
        var comparsion = element.CompareTo(maxValue);
        if (comparsion > 0)
            maxValue = element;
    }
    return maxValue;
}
```

Or

```
public T MaxValue<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, IComparer<T> comparer)
{
    T maxValue = default(T);
    foreach (var element in collection)
    {
        var comparsion = comparer.Compare(element, maxValue);
        if (comparsion > 0)
            maxValue = element;
    }
    return maxValue;
}
```

> How can I code just one method that works both for IEnumerable and
>   ObservableCollection?

`ObservableCollection<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`. What you can do is create an extension method which is applied to any `IEnumerable<T>`, similar to how `LINQ` works via the `System.Linq` namespace:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T MaxValue<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        T maxValue = default(T);
        foreach (var element in collection)
        {
            var comparsion = element.CompareTo(maxValue);
            if (comparsion > 0)
                maxValue = element;
        }
        return maxValue;
    }

    public static T MaxValue<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
       T maxValue = default(T);
       foreach (var element in collection)
       {
           var comparsion = comparer.Compare(element, maxValue);
           if (comparsion > 0)
               maxValue = element;
       }
       return maxValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned in the comments, you're reinventing the wheel; you can use the [`Max`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347632) extension method from Linq.

> If I define a generic method: MaxValue(IEnumerable Collection) how can I assure that no one could use that on a custom type without < > defined? Is this a good thing to be worried of?

You could add a generic constraint to ensure that the type implement `IComparable<T>`:

```
public static T MaxValue<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection) where T : IComparable<T>
```

And use the `CompareTo` method instead of the comparison operator.

> How can I code just one method that works both for IEnumerable and ObservableCollection?

Your method already works for `ObservableCollection<T>`, since it implements `IEnumerable<T>`

---

As a side note, your current implementation has a flaw: it's enumerating the collection twice, which, in the case of a lazy `IEnumerable<T>`, is a bad idea, because enumerating it might cause a database call, or a network request, or whatever. In general, avoid enumerating an enumerable multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

> If I define a generic method: MaxValue(IEnumerable Collection)
>   how can I assure that no one could use that on a custom type without <> defined? > Is this a good thing to be worried of?

For something like this, generic constraints always come in handy, so you could define an interface ie:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

and then write a method:

```
public static decimal MaxValue<T>(IEnumerable<T> myCol) where T : IMyInterface
{
    decimal max = myCol.First().Amount;
   // then iterate collection to find max value, code ommitted
}
```

But as it has been said, there are already ways for you to do this using `linq` so unless there is a real need for you to do this, use what is already available.